# Django + postgreSQL set up

Tags: django, postgresql

This is my first time deploying a django project. I am following this (https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html) as an outline. Everything is good up section 5. where I configure the database. This is what I have currently.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

But this is an existing project and I also have the below in my settings.py and I think they are conflicting since I am not seeing any content populating in my project. What am I doing wrong?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'music:index'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: Those two blocks of settings don't have anything to do with each other. Why do you think they conflict?

Comment: After some testing I found that it was actually working. What threw me off is the django project I am using already had db values but when I run my project they are missing. I found the website itself is functional. Just the values are missing. I guess it doesn't transfer over? I created new items and can see them just fine now.